# How can I relabel a time-related axis using flot?

Tags: jquery, time, resize, label, flot

I'm using flot and jquery libraries to produce a graph of unimolecular decay. Anyways, I am able to display all values in the amount of time it takes in seconds, but my supervisor would like the graph to resize when necessary. It must resize to minutes and hours when necessary, and it must resize back down when necessary. Currently, I have a plot that supports multiple data sets, and if I re-adjust the x values for all data, when I need to relabel the graph, it doesn't seem practical. I will post an image of my plot when I get 10 reputation, as I just created my account. I think it may be possible to adjust the x tick labels manually using the options part of flot, but I am unsure of how to tell when to resize my x-axis in that case. If anyone can please help, I would greatly appreciate any input!

I've started with this, and as for resizing back down to seconds after I have reached hours, I believe I would use maxX < 1 along with conditions for the xAxisLabel. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this. It doesn't seem like it is.

I would call this function inside of gatherData(). gatherData() computes y coordinates for 1000 x-values in the range 0 to maxX and returns a series in the format {data: XYCoords, lines:{show: true}, color: "foo", label: "bar"}.

```
function convertXAxisUnits(xData){
   if (maxX >= 60 && $("#xAxisLabel").innerHTML == "Time(seconds)")
   {
      for (var i = 0; i < xData.length; i++)
      {
         xData[i] /= 60.0;
      }
      maxX /= 60.0;
      $("#xAxisLabel").innerHTML = "Time(minutes)";
   }
   if (maxX >= 60 && $("#xAxisLabel").innerHTML == "Time(minutes)") 
   {
      for (var i = 0; i < xData.length; i++)
      {
         xData[i] /= 60.0;
      }
      maxX /= 60.0;
      $("#xAxisLabel").innerHTML = "Time(hours)";
   }
   //add in conversion going from hours to minutes to seconds
}

function refreshGraph(){
   var options;                                       //graphing options   
   var logarithmic;                                   //option for logarithmic graphing (BOOL)

   dataSets = [];
   maxValue = 0;                                      
   maxX = 0;

   checkForNullValues();
   computeMaxXValue();                                

   if (document.getElementById("switch1").name == "on")                 //push data series 1
   {
      dataSets.push(gatherData("kValue1", "a0Value1"));
   }
   if (document.getElementById("switch2").name == "on")                 //push data series 2
   {
      dataSets.push(gatherData("kValue2", "a0Value2"));
   }
   if (document.getElementById("switch3").name == "on")                 //push data series 3
   {
      dataSets.push(gatherData("kValue3", "a0Value3"));
   }
   if (document.getElementById("switch4").name == "on")                 //push data series 4
   {
      dataSets.push(gatherData("kValue4", "a0Value4"));
   }

   options = {
      yaxis: {max: maxValue},
      grid: {hoverable: true, clickable: true},
      legend: {show: false}
   };

   chart = $.plot($("#panel"), dataSets, options);                      //plot all data series
}
```

Comment: Can you share with us the code that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing your data you can use the `tickFormatter` option and only change the axis / ticks instead:

```
function convertXAxisUnits(xData){
    if (maxX >= 3600) {
        $("#xAxisLabel").html("Time(hours)");
        options.xaxis.tickFormatter: function (value, axis) {
            return value / 3600;
        }
    }
    else if (maxX >= 60) {
        $("#xAxisLabel").html("Time(minutes)");
        options.xaxis.tickFormatter: function (value, axis) {
            return value / 60;
        }
    }
    else {
        $("#xAxisLabel").html("Time(seconds)");
        options.xaxis.tickFormatter: function (value, axis) {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) for more information.

Comment: Ahhh thank you! That makes sense. I will give it a try. I believe I'm able to remove the xData parameter with this solution correct? Also, I would then have to change options to be a global variable or return the result correct?

Comment: Correct. Or you can add the code directly to your `refreshGraph` function.

Comment: I keep getting this error from firebug.  SyntaxError: missing ; before statement options.xaxis.tickFormatter: function (value, axis) {

Comment: I figured it out! Instead of `options.xaxis.tickFormatter:` I had to use `options.xaxis.tickFormatter =`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Good you figured it out.